# Viber og:image tag

Tags: facebook-opengraph, viber, share-open-graph

I have the following URL:
http://ikre.info/vijesti/item/902-cestitka-u-povodu-dana-nezavisnosti-bih.html

and all `og` tags are set:

```html
<meta property="og:image" content="http://ikre.info/media/k2/items/cache/eeca348660096e711cd17c1f61fb2519_L.jpg" />
<meta name="og:image:type" content="image/jpeg" />
<meta name="og:image:width" content="775" />
<meta name="og:image:height" content="516" />
```

But Viber is still ignoring the link if I share it in Viber messenger.

Comment: Check this --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34941283/how-viber-select-the-image-to-display-from-html-page

Comment: I made it a test with a website we have developed and the image is displayed successfully. Our meta are the following: <meta property="og:image" content="http://www.siteurlhere.com/images/main-slider/image-1.jpg" />
    <meta property="og:image:width" content="640" />
    <meta property="og:image:height" content="480" />

Comment: @Kostis i have exactly the same meta tags, but still not working

Answer (score 1):

The response of an image must not be chunked.

There is no documentation. But I revealed that the server should send 200 response with Content-Lenght header

Comment: Sounds more like a comment than an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Same as on https://stackoverflow.com/a/65093512/12640054

> From my test, Viber successfully got **first** jpg/png image on page
> with size **less than 40Kb**.
>
> Even you can hide it with `display: none` if it is not really shown
> image in browser, just for Viber preview.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer. If it is a duplicate question, [vote to close](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) as such and/or leave a comment once you [earn](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/146472) enough [reputation](//stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). If not, *tailor the answer to this specific question*.

Comment: @БогданОпир Дякую). I have not enough reputation for vote to close or comment, so I will leave my answer, because it should help.

Answer (score 0):

I think that Viber does not support the `http` protocol for Open Graph images. Only `https`.