# Viber doesn't show image from URL

Tags: laravel, facebook-opengraph, sharing, viber

I encountered some issues while sharing an image via Viber. First time I've tried to use Open Graph protocol and it didn't help (Slack, Facebook, Skype are ok). After that, I tried to share just an image from my site:

https://autokos.com.ua/public/images/avtokos.png

And nothing happened in Viber (Slack, Facebook, Skype are ok)

If I try to share, for example, this one URL https://support.viber.com/customer/portal/attachments/830459  - all ok in Viber, Facebook, Skype, etc.

Server: nginx/1.14.2

Thx

Comment: Any updates on the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Related answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/65093512/12640054

> From my test, Viber successfully got **first** jpg/png image on page
> with size **less than 40Kb**.
>
> Even you can hide it with `display: none` if it is not really shown
> image in browser, just for Viber preview.

May be the same rule for direct images links.

Answer (score 1):

I had issue with png and viber too.
Converting that image to jpg solved issue for me.

If picture is very big, that could maybe lead to ignore (mine is 150kb and works fine).
Hope this helps :)